# How to prevent a page break before an itemize list?

Tags: lists, page-breaking

It is not nice to have a page break right after the colon and have the list start on a new page:

```
And here, finally, is the list of mission-critical items:
\begin{itemize}
...
\end{itemize}
```

How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
\makeatletter 
\newcommand\mynobreakpar{\par\nobreak\@afterheading} 
\makeatother
.....
text\mynobreakpar
\begin{itemize}
....
```

Comment: It works but somehow swallows the vertical space before itemize.

Comment: @user87690 to avoid that add `\vspace{\baselineskip}`, like this: `\newcommand\mynobreakpar{\vspace{\baselineskip}\par\nobreak\@afterheading} 
`

Answer (score 32):

LaTeX puts `\beginparpenalty` at the begin of a list. The standard classes set `\@beginparpenalty` to `-\@lowpenalty` (-51), i.e., they somewhat encourage page breaks before  lists. If you want to avoid page breaks before lists at all costs, set `\@beginparpenalty` to 10000 in the preamble of your document.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\@beginparpenalty=10000
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{itemize}
\item \lipsum*[6]
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there some way to change the penalty for a specific list?

Comment: @svick: "List" meaning "type of list" or "instance of a list environment"?

Comment: @user946850 I meant a specific instance of a list.

Comment: In this case you can surround the definition of the list by a group and set `\@beginparpenalty` inside the group: `{\makeatletter...\begin{itemize}...\end{itemize}}`

Answer (score 22):

`enumitem`'s `beginpenalty` parameter is still missing here, and is specially convenient (adapting [lockstep's MWE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46795/105447)):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{itemize}[beginpenalty=10000]
\item \lipsum*[6]
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Top anwer, thanks so much! :)

Comment: `enumitem` package has also `midpenalty` and `endpenalty` parameters, which can be useful to handle widowed/orphaned list items: http://www.texnia.com/archive/enumitem.pdf#subsection.3.5

Answer (score 13):

Another solution, similar to [Corbie's one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/317681/128824), is use of *samepage* environment in way below. It's enough to use it on first item in list (or a few first ones), so you can use it without suppressing page-break either in preceding paragraph and in whole list. Also, *minipage* environment is probably overkill comparing to *samepage* and you need not specify line width, but it's matter of taste, you can use it too.

```
And here, finally, is the list of mission-critical items:
\begin{itemize}
\begin{samepage} % first item is tied to end of preceding paragraph
    \item first item...
\end{samepage}
    ... % second and following items
\end{itemize}
```

Answer (score 6):

The `\mynobreakpar` solution does met work properly for user87690 (see comment on the `\mynobreakpar` solution), because in his scope, the paragraph separator is zero, but the list top separator is not. So it seems better to use the macro `\nolisttopbreak` below instead.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nolisttopbreak}{\vspace{\topsep}\nobreak\@afterheading}
\makeatother
.....
text\nolisttopbreak
\begin{itemize}
....
```

As you can see, then is no `\par`, so the paragraph separator is not used.

Comment: While this might answer the question, it's sometimes better to provide a full example instead of a fragment

Comment: I have copied the corresponding parts of the original solution, so that this solution can live on its own.

Comment: This does not seem to work here, but Ulrike’s variant does.

Comment: @Joachim Breitner. I agree both solutions have a different effect. But your claim is opposite to the reason of adding my solution: the experience that the other (mine) solution is the working one. It might be the context that makes the difference.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer moving the introduction to a minipage:

```
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  And here, finally, is the list of mission-critical items:
  \begin{itemize}
  ...
  \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
```

Note that this prevents page breaks inside the list too.

Comment: Good point. I think the minipage is only useful, if you have a short list.