# No page break before a heading, while preserving some vertical space before heading?

Tags: spacing, sectioning, page-breaking

How can I prevent a page break before a run-in section heading while preserving vertical spacing before the heading?

Based on the suggestion in [How to prevent a page break before an itemize list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2644/6510), I have defined a run-in heading as

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\runinheading}{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                         {2.1ex \@plus1ex \@minus 0.64ex}{-1em}%
                                         {\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries}}
\newcommand{\nobreakruninheading}{\par\nobreak\@afterheading\runinheading}
\makeatother
```

I use this heading in the following way:

```
..., but the process assignment is still in bijective
correspondence with the proof rules.

\nobreakruninheading*{Cut reduction as computation.}
The principal cut reduction is
\begin{equation*}
\text{several lines of math go here}
\end{equation*}
When annotated according to the process interpretation,
we can extract the process reduction
```

Indeed, LaTeX does not insert a page break before the run-in heading.  However, there is no vertical space between the end of the paragraph (`... with the proof rules.`) and the run-in heading.

I do know that there is enough room on the page with `1.6ex` of vertical space prior to the heading because if I instead define `\nobreakruninheading*` as `\vspace{1.6ex}\noindent{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries #1}\hspace{1em}`, everything fits the way I want.  I'd like to avoid resorting to this alternate definition, if possible, because it does not match the other section headings in my paper (which use `\@startsection`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My feeling is that if you *want* vertical space before the runin heading, then a page break is good as well.

Anyway, you get what you ask by adding the spacing after `\nobreak`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\runinheading}{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                         {2.1ex \@plus1ex \@minus 0.64ex}{-1em}%
                                         {\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries}}
\newcommand{\nobreakruninheading}{\par\nobreak\vskip\bigskipamount\@afterheading\runinheading}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I would certainly agree that normally a page break should be good as well.  This is for a conference submission, though, and space is very tight; it seems that a page break here is the critical point that pushes the paper over the page limit.  I wish I didn't have to resort to this kind of hackery...