# How to avoid page breaks before enumerate/itemize by default?

Tags: page-breaking

Basically the same as [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2644/how-to-prevent-a-page-break-before-an-itemize-list), except I don't want to have to remember to write `\mynobreakpar` (or anything else) everywhere.

How do I set this as the default option for all itemize/enumerate/etc. environments?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if this is overkill but one workaround is by using `etoolbox` package. I took the liberty of copying Ulrike Fischer's macro from your link.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter 
\newcommand\mynobreakpar{\par\nobreak\@afterheading} 
\makeatother

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{itemize}{
\mynobreakpar
}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    Some text
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 2
        \item Item 3
    \end{itemize}
    \lipsum[1-4]
    Here is an intervening paragraph. Does this answer your needs? Because the quick brown fox jumps over the head of the lazy dog. And the quick brown fox jumps over the head of the lazy dog.
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh interesting, I hadn't seen `etoolbox` before, +1 thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an alternative solution. I would create my own version of the environments for which you want this feature to apply:

```
\makeatletter 
\newcommand\mynobreakpar{\par\nobreak\@afterheading} 
\makeatother
\newenvironment{myitemize}{\mynobreakpar\begin{itemize}}{\end{itemize}}
```

Comment: I just tried it with you MWE.  It seems to work.

Comment: Hmmm... Strange. It does now as well it should. I wonder what happened to my compilation earlier. I would upvote this but I am out of votes for now.

Comment: Worked for me. I did need to add an extra \\ to the end of the paragraph before the itemize to get the spacing I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why a new paragraph should be lauched before the list. Actually, it seems that you need to take into account the effects of `\par` to get what you want.

There is only one situation where I do not like page breaks before lists. Furthermore, I do not like list tags not being aligned. This has led to the following.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nolisttopbreak}{\vspace{\topsep}\nobreak\@afterheading}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{listproof}[1][\proofname]{\begin{proof}[#1]\mbox{}\nolisttopbreak}{\end{proof}}
```

As you can see, there is no paragraph break anywhere.

`\@afterheading` is probably just what a `\begin{proof}` generates, so that the first list item is started right after the `\proofname` command without any linebreak or vertical space in between.

Comment: Oops, this is an answer for another question, namely the question where the questioner refers to. Sorry.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If this is 'wrong' in the sense of the real question, you should either edit or delete it

Comment: It has already been accepted and edited, so I cannot delete it any more. I copied the edited version to the right location. Any moderator may delete this answer, as far as I am concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Using [my own answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/360906/128824) in question referenced by asker, you can redefine *item* macro to let it work for lists environments. It's absolutely transparent, you don't event have to using own environment.

```
\let\nativeitem\item
\renewcommand{\item}{
    \begin{samepage} % prevent page-break before list enviroment
    \nativeitem\ % character needed after \item
    \end{samepage}\pagebreak[2] % page-break opportunity after (and only after) every item
}
```

Comment: Instead of the control space (character needed after `\item`), you could use `\mbox{}`.