# How to prevent pagebreaking before example environment?

Tags: page-breaking, examples

In my document, the page happens to break right after the line that introduces an example environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}
\noindent Here are my results:
    \begin{exe}
        \ex This is my first result.
        \ex This is my second result.
    \end{exe}
\end{document}
```

I tried to put `Here are my results:\nobreak`, as indicated [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2644/how-to-prevent-a-page-break-before-an-itemize-list), but that changed nothing for me. What should I do?

Comment: Try `\makeatletter\@afterheading\makeatother`.

Comment: I tried ``Here are my results:\makeatletter\@afterheading\makeatother``, but that didn't work.

Comment: if you insert `\goodbreak` before the line "Here are my results:" that would encourage latex to push that line to the next page if it's within a line or two of the bottom of the page, and wouldn't do anything if there's more space than that.  not a great approach, but better than a page forced by `\newpage`.  (i didn't go into `gb4e`, but it's likely that surgery there would be necessary to permit something like `\nobreak` to be effective.)

Comment: Oops, sorry. I think you need `\par \nobreak\makeatletter\@afterheading\makeatother`. Sorry for groping in the dark, but your MWE has no page break ;-)

Comment: barbara's ``\goodbreak`` works fine. Stephan's latter approach works too, but it also removes the vertical space that's normally above the ``exe`` environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you insert `\goodbreak` before the line "Here are my results:" that would encourage latex to push that line to the next page if it's within a line or two of the bottom of the page, and wouldn't do anything if there's more space than that. not a great approach, but better than a page forced by `\newpage`.

i didn't go into `gb4e`, but it's likely that surgery there would be necessary to permit something like `\nobreak` to be effective.