# Avoid page break between line and quote environment

Tags: page-breaking

I encountered a little problem while writing my homework in LaTeX.
I wrote the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\center{Title}
\vspace{18cm}\\
This line should be on the same page as the next one.
\begin{quote}
This line should be on the same page as the previous one.\\
This one could be broken to another page if needed.
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

But LaTeX breaks the page right after the first line, which I want to avoid.
Both `\nopagebreak` and `\\*` do not seem to work for me here. 
Any advice?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: `\nopagebreak` will make it infinitely bad, to break there but depending on what else is on the page all choices might be infinitely bad. Please edit your question to make a [full example document](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that#answer-3225) that shows the problem

Comment: I hope the added example adds some clarity.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to use [the `needspace` package](http://www.tex.ac.uk/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/needspace/) to specify how many lines are to be kept together.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{needspace}
\begin{document}
\center{Title}
\vspace{18cm}\\
\needspace{3\baselineskip}% <------- Page break added if space less than 3\baselineskip
This line should be on the same page as the next one.
\begin{quote}
This line should be on the same page as the previous one.\\
This one could be broken to another page if needed.
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The list environment inserts  a (negative) `\@beginparpenalty` which rather encourages page breaking at that point. You can (locally or globally) set it to 10000 to discourage breaking.

I also modified the `\center` and removed the `\\` which should never follow `\vspace`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}Title\end{center}

\vspace{18cm}
This line should be on the same page as the next one.
\csname @beginparpenalty\endcsname10000
\begin{quote}
This line should be on the same page as the previous one.\\
This one could be broken to another page if needed.
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `quote` environment is internally represented as a list and the trick from the question "[How to prevent a page break before an itemize list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2644/)" also works for `quote` environmments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter 
\newcommand\mynobreakpar{\par\nobreak\@afterheading} 
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\center{Title}
\vspace{18cm}\\
This line should be on the same page as the next one.\mynobreakpar
\begin{quote}
This line should be on the same page as the previous one.\\
This one could be broken to another page if needed.
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

Unrelated: the `\\` after the `\vspace` looks odd to me.  Maybe it should be removed?

Comment: the line `\center{Title}` doesn't get into vertical mode, so removing `\\` makes the "This line" line continue on the same line as "Title".  a blank line or `\par` before the `\vspace` is probably a more appropriate mod.