# Keep item and includegraphics or figure on same page

Tags: lists, page-breaking, samepage

I'm creating a software guide where I use enumerated list for the steps. Many of the steps have a screenshot I display under the item. I'd like to keep the item and the following figure or graphic together. I've tried Samepage, which does not work. I've also tried minipages, which works but  complicates the enumerated list. I'd have thousands of minipages if I did use it. My solution thus far was to add manual pagebreaks or clearpage. I'd prefer code so I don't have to continually edit the manual breaks.

MWE

```
    \section{Section Name}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Directions go here
    \FloatBarrier \begin{figure[!h]
    \centering\includegraphics[scale=0.65]{ImageA.png}
    \end{figure} \FloatBarrier
    \item Next step in directions.
    \FloatBarrier \begin{figure[!h]
    \centering\includegraphics[scale=0.65]{ImageB.png}
    \end{figure} \FloatBarrier
    \item Step three.
    \FloatBarrier \begin{figure[!h]
    \centering\includegraphics[scale=0.65]{ImageC.png}
    \end{figure} \FloatBarrier
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: How about **not** using floating figures at all? I.e. drop the 'dreadful' `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}`. At the moment, you're not even using `\caption`, there's no need to let them float around!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need not have `\includegraphics` within a `figure` environment.  In particular, if you want to place images inline within the text, you might as well use the `center` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\section{Section Name}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Directions go here
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-a}
  \end{center}
\item Next step in directions.
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-b}
  \end{center}
\item Step three.
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-c}
  \end{center}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Note that this, on its own, simply makes it easier to place the images but it does not prevent a page breaks between the text and the `center` environment.  If you really want to force them being together, there are two options: either use the `samepage` environment, or define a new `\par` that prevents a page break (taken from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115621/26980)).  Both are illustrated below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter 
\newcommand\nobreakpar{\par\nobreak\@afterheading} 
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Section Name}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Directions go here   % This allows a page break
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[height=6cm]{example-image-a}
  \end{center}
\item Next step in directions. \nobreakpar % No page break here
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[height=6cm]{example-image-b}
  \end{center}
\item
  \begin{samepage}  % No page break anywhere inside this environment
    Step three.
    \begin{center}
      \includegraphics[height=6cm]{example-image-c}
    \end{center}
  \end{samepage}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `center` environment might add too much vertical spacing, perhaps. `\centering` is possible too, in a group, of course, but this depends on the O.P.'s personal preferences, of course

Comment: Thanks Christian. So I trade floats for \begin{center} and \end{center}. I'll see if that adds too much vertical white space. I was able to control the vertical white space of the figures. While your suggestion helps clean up code, it does not solve my initial issue of separated images from the item.

Comment: @PepPaddy: Your comment is unclear and your code is by far complete. The solution by JP-Ellis should work, in my point of view

Comment: Thanks JP-Ellis. Using your example, I am still getting images pushed to the next page with the step instructions on the previous page.

Comment: This is not possible. Only the last images, if it is to large for the rest of page, is pushed to the next page.

Comment: @PepPaddy I have update the answer to address the issue of the image moving onto the next page.  Note that you should be careful when using these commands as they can easily cause the formatting to go wrong.

Comment: Thank you JP-Ellis! So the samepage works. I had tried it but put it in the wrong place. The code I tried was \begin{samepage} \item Step directions \includegraphics \end{samepage}. I also tried the nobreakpar, but that didn't work.