# Prevent page break without removing vertical space

Tags: spacing, lists, page-breaking, paragraphs

I have a single sentence paragraph that introduces a list, and LaTeX is trying to insert a page break between the paragraph and its list, which I find unacceptable.  I can prevent that page break with `\@nobreaktrue`, but then I lose the vertical space between the paragraph and its list.  How can I prevent a page break between the paragraph and its list without losing the normal vertical space I'd expect there?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\reallynopagebreak}{\par\@nobreaktrue\nopagebreak}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Paragraph introducing list:\reallynopagebreak{}

\begin{itemize}
\item list
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Unwanted result, no space between paragraph and list:

[image]

For now I've just done `\vspace{\baselineskip}` at the end of the paragraph, but surely that's not the best way?

Comment: Would a conditional be the best way you want?

Comment: I'm not opposed to employing a conditional to fix this, or better a macro which uses a conditional, if that's what you're asking Jesse?  Sorry if I misunderstood you.

Comment: Use \@afterheading.

Comment: Sorry Ulrike, I did some searching but I don't understand what you mean by "use \@afterheading".  I tried putting that in my document in various places to no avail.  Google wasn't much help, either.  Could you provide a bigger hint?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer I'd prefer today is [lockstep's answer for preventing page break before itemize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2644/how-to-prevent-a-page-break-before-an-itemize-list).  Here's my MWE above adapted to demonstrate this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

% Provide enough content such that LaTeX would normally break between
% "Paragraph introducing list:" and the actual list.  Please forgive
% my imperial units.
\vspace*{1.1in}
\lipsum[1-4]

Paragraph introducing list:

\begingroup
\makeatletter
% Strongly encourage LaTeX not to break before this list.
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46795/1680
\@beginparpenalty=10000
\makeatother
\begin{itemize}
\item list
\end{itemize}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking a different tack, I introduce `\ListIntro` macro, which will automatically check for enough space to get the list going, or else page break.

To test the alternative, with no intervention, uncomment the line redefining the `\ListIntro` macro to `{#1}`, which merely passes on the argument unaltered.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand\ListIntro[1]{%
  \def\intpar{\parbox{\textwidth}{#1}}%
  \needspace{\heightof{\intpar}+3\baselineskip}%
  #1%
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]

%\def\ListIntro#1{#1}

\ListIntro{\lipsum[5]}

\begin{itemize}
\item list
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks much!  I'm liking your use of `\heightof` plus `\needspace` there.  I'm not crazy about having to wrap the introductory paragraph to every list in this document with `\ListIntro`, but it may come to pass that this is really the best solution.  I'm going to let this sit a little while longer and see if any more suggestions pop up.