# How to label a list / make a line before list stick with the list?

Tags: lists, page-breaking

I am getting frustrated by not being able to "label" lists in a way where the "label" would stick with the list and a page break (or column break) would not be introduced before it.

Here is a [MWE](https://www.overleaf.com/read/zsqndcjfxzdd):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[defaultlines=2,all]{nowidow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{parskip}

\tolerance=1000

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\indexClass}[1]{\index{#1}}
\newcommand{\class}[1]{#1\indexClass{#1}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\WviiTwoColumnSetup}{\raggedcolumns\RaggedRight}

\SetEnumitemKey{WviiTwoColumn}{%
  before=\begin{multicols}{2}\WviiTwoColumnSetup,
  after=\end{multicols}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

Convenient Starting Professions\nobreak\nopagebreak\begin{itemize}[WviiTwoColumn]\nopagebreak%
\item \class{Fighter}
\item \class{Thief}
\item \class{Ranger}
\item \class{Bishop}
\item \class{Ninja}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

If you look at its rendering, you should notice that my "Convenient Starting Professions" label is at page 1 but the list itself is at page 2, despite my desperate attempts to discourage the page break.

[image]

(I am using XeLaTeX.)

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161703/prevent-page-breaks-between-item-heading-and-item-content

Comment: @JohnKormylo: I will try the `stackengine` solution of the question. One thing I see is different is that in my case, the `itemize` is wrapped with `multicols`.

Comment: The needspace approach should work if you make the space big enough,  I have no idea about stackengine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to avoid page breaks in the whole object:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[defaultlines=2,all]{nowidow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{parskip}

\newcommand{\indexClass}[1]{\index{#1}}
\newcommand{\class}[1]{#1\indexClass{#1}}

\newenvironment{twocolumnitemize}[1]
 {%
  \par\noindent
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \begin{multicols}{2}[#1]
  \raggedcolumns\RaggedRight
  \begin{itemize}
 }
 {%
  \end{itemize}
  \end{multicols}
  \end{minipage}
 }

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{twocolumnitemize}{Convenient Starting Professions}
\item \class{Fighter}
\item \class{Thief}
\item \class{Ranger}
\item \class{Bishop}
\item \class{Ninja}
\end{twocolumnitemize}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

By removing the `minipage`, you get possible page breaks only in the itemized list.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[defaultlines=2,all]{nowidow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{parskip}

\newcommand{\indexClass}[1]{\index{#1}}
\newcommand{\class}[1]{#1\indexClass{#1}}

\newenvironment{twocolumnitemize}[1]
 {%
  \begin{multicols}{2}[#1]
  \raggedcolumns\RaggedRight
  \begin{itemize}
 }
 {%
  \end{itemize}
  \end{multicols}
 }

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{twocolumnitemize}{Convenient Starting Professions}
\item \class{Fighter}
\item \class{Thief}
\item \class{Ranger}
\item \class{Bishop}
\item \class{Ninja}
\end{twocolumnitemize}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess I don't need to point this out, but your understanding of grouping is ridiculously sophisticated.  Making multicols work for this question was not even on my radar. Very good answer.

Comment: @AFeldman I happened to remember the optional argument feature of `multicols` and tried. 

Comment: After reading your answer I went back to `multicol`'s documentation and found the parameter documented. I did not see it previous because I just skimmed the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

***Two Answers***

#### 1- For Short Lists

Using a `\vtop` box:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[defaultlines=2,all]{nowidow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{parskip}

\tolerance=1000

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\indexClass}[1]{\index{#1}}
\newcommand{\class}[1]{#1\indexClass{#1}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\WviiTwoColumnSetup}{\raggedcolumns\RaggedRight}

\SetEnumitemKey{WviiTwoColumn}{%
  before=\begin{multicols}{2}\WviiTwoColumnSetup,
  after=\end{multicols}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

\vtop{%

 Convenient Starting Professions%

  \begin{itemize}[WviiTwoColumn]%

     \item \class{Fighter}
     \item \class{Thief}
     \item \class{Ranger}
     \item \class{Bishop}
     \item \class{Ninja}

  \end{itemize}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### 1- For Long Lists

Per the OP's stated use for very long lists to break over pages. This uses the `longtable` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\def\It{\textbullet\hskip.2in}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\indexClass}[1]{\index{#1}}
\newcommand{\class}[1]{#1\indexClass{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
     \lipsum[1-2]
        \begin{longtable}[l]{llll}

            \caption*{\bfseries\hskip1in Convenient Starting Professions}\\
               \multicolumn{4}{l}

                        \endfirsthead

        \It \class{Fighter} & \It \class{Bishop}\\
        \It \class{Thief} & \It \class{Ninja}\\     
        \It \class{Ranger} & ~\\
        \It \class{Fighter} & \It \class{Bishop}\\
        \It \class{Thief} & \It \class{Ninja}\\     
        \It \class{Ranger} & ~\\
        \It \class{Fighter} & \It \class{Bishop}\\
        \It \class{Thief} & \It \class{Ninja}\\     
        \It \class{Ranger} & ~\\
        \It \class{Fighter} & \It \class{Bishop}\\
        \It \class{Thief} & \It \class{Ninja}\\     
        \It \class{Ranger} & ~\\
        \It \class{Fighter} & \It \class{Bishop}\\
        \It \class{Thief} & \It \class{Ninja}\\     
        \It \class{Ranger} & ~\\
        \It \class{Fighter} & \It \class{Bishop}\\
        \It \class{Thief} & \It \class{Ninja}\\     
        \It \class{Ranger} & ~\\
        \It \class{Fighter} & \It \class{Bishop}\\
        \It \class{Thief} & \It \class{Ninja}\\     
        \It \class{Ranger} & ~\\
        \It \class{Fighter} & \It \class{Bishop}\\
        \It \class{Thief} & \It \class{Ninja}\\     
        \It \class{Ranger} & ~\\
        \It \class{Fighter} & \It \class{Bishop}\\
        \It \class{Thief} & \It \class{Ninja}\\     
        \It \class{Ranger} & ~\\
        \It \class{Fighter} & \It \class{Bishop}\\
        \It \class{Thief} & \It \class{Ninja}\\     
        \It \class{Ranger} & ~\\

        \end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By using a `\phantom` the columns may be separated, for instance:

`\It Fighter \phantom{\hskip2in}  & \It Bishop\\`

(only for the first entry) produces:

[image]

For a bit more room between the items a `\strut` can be added to the definition of `\It`, `\def\It{\textbullet\hskip.2in{\Large\strut}}` producing:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. However, while this works for this small list, I have other lists that are much bigger. Wouldn't putting them in `\vtop` force LaTeX to break the page early and leave me with half page of empty space?

Comment: Yes, that's definitely right. That is if the list is long enough to force the page to break.  And another problem is that the `\vtop` will never be able to make a list that exceeds the page that it starts on.  So it is not a great solution for longer lists. Maybe something using _Stackengine_ https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/stackengine?lang=en or even _longtable_ https://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable?lang=en might work better in this situation.

Comment: @wilx Added a longtable solution.