# "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item" error in \newenvironment using a \vtop box

Tags: macros, environments, boxes, expansion

In attempting an answer to [*"How to label a list / make a line before list stick with the list?"*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/312509/90087) I answered using a `\vtop` box to contain the entire list including the label.  I then, trying to improve upon my answer, attempted to place the solution within its own environment using a `\newenvironment` which I called `Imyz`.  This did not work, the log contains two error messages:

error 1: `Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.`

error 2: `Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment.`

The code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[defaultlines=2,all]{nowidow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{parskip}

\tolerance=1000

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\indexClass}[1]{\index{#1}}
\newcommand{\class}[1]{#1\indexClass{#1}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\WviiTwoColumnSetup}{\raggedcolumns\RaggedRight}

\SetEnumitemKey{WviiTwoColumn}{%
  before=\begin{multicols}{2}\WviiTwoColumnSetup,
  after=\end{multicols}}

\newenvironment{Imyz}[1]{%
    \vtop{%
        #1%
         \begin{itemize}[ WviiTwoColumn]}%
             {\end{itemize}}%
    }

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

    \vtop{%

        Convenient Starting Professions%

     \begin{itemize}[WviiTwoColumn]%

            \item \class{Fighter}
            \item \class{Thief}
            \item \class{Ranger}
            \item \class{Bishop}
            \item \class{Ninja}

         \end{itemize}%
   }

\begin{Imyz}{Convenient Starting Professions}

    \item \class{Fighter}
    \item \class{Thief}
    \item \class{Ranger}
    \item \class{Bishop}
    \item \class{Ninja}

\end{Imyz}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

As evident from the output, and the errors, my new environment does not work to start and end the `itemize` environment with the added `\vtop` box with the label included. Any help and any explanation of why this did not work would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're starting and ending the `\vtop` in the “begin” part, so `\begin{itemize}` is executed and the box ends before the contents of the environment is even examined.

TeX allows starting a box with `\bgroup` and ending it with `\egroup`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[defaultlines=2,all]{nowidow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{parskip}

\newcommand{\WviiTwoColumnSetup}{\raggedcolumns\RaggedRight}

\SetEnumitemKey{WviiTwoColumn}{%
  before=\begin{multicols}{2}\WviiTwoColumnSetup,
  after=\vfill\end{multicols}}

\newenvironment{Imyz}[1]
 {\vtop\bgroup #1%
  \begin{itemize}[WviiTwoColumn]}
 {\end{itemize}\egroup}

\newcommand{\indexClass}[1]{\index{#1}}
\newcommand{\class}[1]{#1\indexClass{#1}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

    \vtop{%

        Convenient Starting Professions%

     \begin{itemize}[WviiTwoColumn]%

            \item \class{Fighter}
            \item \class{Thief}
            \item \class{Ranger}
            \item \class{Bishop}
            \item \class{Ninja}

         \end{itemize}%
   }

\begin{Imyz}{Convenient Starting Professions}

    \item \class{Fighter}
    \item \class{Thief}
    \item \class{Ranger}
    \item \class{Bishop}
    \item \class{Ninja}

\end{Imyz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and most certainly for the great explanation of why what I tried did not work.