# How to insert multiple paragraphs in a \cventry

Tags: moderncv

Here is the syntax of `\cventry`:

```
\cventry{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{desc}
```

How to insert multiple paragraph in a `desc` part. Also it seems that `cventry` does not span in multiple pages which make the CV to seem awkward.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the first problem, without redefining anything you can just use `\endgraf` at the desired paragraph break:

```
\cventry{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{desc .... \endgraf descr ...}
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 

\moderncvstyle{casual} 
\moderncvcolor{blue}   

\usepackage{lipsum} %Just for dummy text

\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resum\'e title}  

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description
text that is long and stretches over several lines.  Description
text that is long and stretches over several lines.  Description
text that is long and stretches over several lines.  Description
text that is long and stretches over several lines.  \endgraf Description
text that is long and stretches over several lines.  Description
text that is long and stretches over several lines.  Description
text that is long and stretches over several lines.  Description
text that is long and stretches over several lines.} 

\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{\lipsum[1-10]}
\end{document}
```

For the page breaks, you need to redefine `\cventry`.  In the process you may as well allow ordinary paragraph breaks in the description (by making this a "long" command).  The approach below is to define `\cventry`s as items in a special list customised via the `enumitem` pakcage.  If this interferes with other uses of `\cventry` then you could define a newcommands `\longcventry` and `\longcvitem` with the definitions below and leave the original definitions intact.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 

\moderncvstyle{casual} 
\moderncvcolor{blue}   

\usepackage{enumitem}

\renewcommand{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    .\strut%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{}}{}%
    {\newline{\small\strut #7 \par}}}}

\renewcommand{\cvitem}[3][.25em]{%
  \begin{mycvlist}
    \item[#2] #3
    \end{mycvlist}
    \addvspace{#1}}

\newlist{mycvlist}{description}{1}
\setlist[mycvlist]{labelwidth=\hintscolumnwidth,labelsep=\separatorcolumnwidth,leftmargin=!,align=right,font=\normalfont}

\usepackage{lipsum} %Just for dummy text

\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resum\'e title}  

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description
text that is long and stretches over several lines.  Description
text that is long and stretches over several lines.  Description
text that is long and stretches over several lines.  Description
text that is long and stretches over several lines.  \par Description
text that is long and stretches over several lines.  Description
text that is long and stretches over several lines.  Description
text that is long and stretches over several lines.  Description
text that is long and stretches over several lines.} 

\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{\lipsum[1-10]}
\end{document}
```

The reason some redefinition is necessary, is that as standard `cventry` builds a `tabular` and then puts the description part in a `minipage`, but neither `tabular` nor `minipage` will break over pages.

*Addition*  If you need long labels then you need to use a slightly more elaborate definition for `\cvitem` wrapping the label in a box and making sure the text inside is right aligned:

```
\renewcommand{\cvitem}[3][.25em]{%
  \begin{mycvlist}
    \item[{\parbox[t][\baselineskip]{\hintscolumnwidth}{\raggedleft #2}}] #3
    \end{mycvlist}
    \addvspace{#1}}
```

Unfortunately `enumitem` does not contain a standard option for this.  Here is code, in the newer style of moderncv, without a fullstop at the end of the first line.

[image: Multi-page sample]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\renewcommand{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    \strut
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{}}{\par\vspace{-0.8\baselineskip}}{%
    \newline\small\strut #7 \par}}}

\renewcommand{\cvitem}[3][.25em]{%
  \begin{mycvlist}
    \item[{\parbox[t][\baselineskip]{\labelwidth}{\raggedleft #2}}] #3
    \end{mycvlist}
    \addvspace{#1}}

\newlist{mycvlist}{description}{1}
\setlist[mycvlist]{labelwidth=\hintscolumnwidth,labelsep=\separatorcolumnwidth,align=right,leftmargin=!,font=\normalfont}

\usepackage{lipsum} %Just for dummy text

\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resum\'e title}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{\lipsum[2]}

\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{}

\cventry{year--year, year--year and year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{\lipsum[1-10]}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great answer but a few remarks. 1) I needed to replace in cvlist the `\labelwidth` with `\hintscolumnwidth` otherwise it would not have the appropriate width if you change this parameter (particularly visible with `\tlcventry`) 2) the spacing is significantly larger that what I get by default. In my experience, using `nosep` in the `\setlist`, replacing the `\baselineskip` with `.85em`, and adding a condition for empty contents like `.\strut\ifthenelse{\equal{\detokenize{#7}}{}}{\vspace{1.1mm}}{\newline{\small\strut #7 \par}}}}` gives me a much closer look.

Comment: @tobiasBora Many thanks for these comments.  I have updated the code: `\hintscolumnwidth` is now used consistently.  I also now check for an empty last argument

Comment: Hey, me again ^^ I found that a page break can occur between the title and its content… Is it possible somehow to forbid this, as it is really inelegant? I tried to insert various `\nopagebreak` or follow https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2644/how-to-prevent-a-page-break-before-an-itemize-list (my item inside being a list)… without success.

Comment: @tobiasBora Agreed that is undesirable.  I local experiment suggests adding `\nopagebreak` before and after `\newline` in `\cventry` and before and after `\addvspace{#1}` in `\cvitem` may work.   Is that a solution for you?

Comment: @tobiasBora If not, you can manually add `\clearpage` before a breaking `\cventry`

Comment: I tried but without success. I added a question here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/700920/how-to-cleanly-forbid-page-break What works is `\Needspace{5\baseline}` before a new item, but this looks a bit dirty solution.

Answer (score 1):

Very late answer, I know, but I found Andrew's response to be excellent. The only issue I had was that some of the text from the first argument of `\cventry` and `\cvitem` was inside the left margin. This happened because the text in these arguments was longer than the allocated width. I fixed this by changing the align option. I changed

`\setlist[mycvlist]{labelwidth=\hintscolumnwidth,labelsep=\separatorcolumnwidth,leftmargin=!,align=right,font=\normalfont}`

to

`\setlist[mycvlist]{labelwidth=\hintscolumnwidth,labelsep=\separatorcolumnwidth,leftmargin=!,align=parleft,font=\normalfont}`.

This will seem trivial to many people, but as a fairly new user this wasn't obvious to me.

Comment: Good point.  However, this changes the alignment of labels to the left rather than the right.  Fixing that needs more work, and I have now added such a version to my answer.