# Break moderncv cventry into multiple pages without using list items

Tags: environments, page-breaking, moderncv

This has been asked before, for example, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168537/how-to-insert-multiple-paragraphs-in-a-cventry) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139128/106952). However, they seem to alter the original settings, which is not needed for me. I am trying to use similar command to **just allow the text to be split into multiple pages**, nothing more. But, I don't know how to write the `newcommand` to fit my requirement.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        

\moderncvstyle{classic}                             
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               
\bibliographystyle{alpha}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}                               
\phone[mobile]{+123~(45)~678~9101}                   
\email{first.last@example.com}                       

\makeatletter\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}\makeatother

\newcommand\Colorhref[3][cyan]{\href{#2}{\small\color{#1}#3}}

%\newcommand*{\cventrylong}{<Something here>}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{multibib}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%--------------------------------------------
%            content
%--------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle
\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
\vspace*{-\baselineskip}


\section{Some Title}
\cvline{Primary}{\lipsum[1]}
\cvline{Secondary}{\lipsum[2]}

\section{Work Experience}
\subsection{Professional}
\cventry{09/16--08/17}{Title}{Worksplace}{City, Country}{}
{\lipsum[3-6]}

\end{document}
```

Like I mentioned before, if I use the solution presented [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139128/106952), the final pdf looks as follows:

[image: finalpdf]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This should have been asked on the main site.

Comment: True. I realized that I asked it in the wrong place. How to move to the main site?

Comment: How to check that? The tex file says Copyright 2006-2015, I believe it is version 2.0.0. It is taken from [here](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/moderncv-cv-and-cover-letter)

Comment: Check the log file. There you will find the version number, seems to be `\ProvidesClass{moderncv}[2012/10/31 v1.2.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter document class]`. That means this version is outdated and some advices here will not work ... Better use the current version ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your used command `\cventry` is defined in version 2.0.0 of `moderncv` to use a `minipage` to be able to layout the last argument `...--7`. The minipage **can not span** two pages!

But there is a workaround:  You have to play with the length of the text as argument `--7`. For your given code you can find for example:

```
\cventry{09/16--08/17--2}%
  {Title--3}%
  {Worksplace--4}%
  {City, Country--5}%
  {--6}
  {\lipsum[3-4]--7}
```

Now you can use

```
\cvitem{}{\lipsum[5-6]}
```

to add the missing text ...

Because `minipage` can not go over more than one page you have to do this manually ...

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}                               
\phone[mobile]{+123~(45)~678~9101}                   
\email{first.last@example.com}                       

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
\makeatother

\newcommand\Colorhref[3][cyan]{\href{#2}{\small\color{#1}#3}}

%\newcommand*{\cventrylong}{<Something here>}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{multibib}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%--------------------------------------------
%            content
%--------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle
\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
\vspace*{-\baselineskip}


\section{Some Title}
\cvline{Primary}{\lipsum[1]}
\cvline{Secondary}{\lipsum[2]}

\section{Work Experience}
\subsection{Professional}
\cventry{09/16--08/17--2}%
  {Title--3}%
  {Worksplace--4}%
  {City, Country--5}%
  {--6}
  {\lipsum[3-4]--7}
\cvitem{}{\lipsum[5-6]}

\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image]

## UPDATE:

To get an automatic break you have to change the construct of command `\cventry`. Do **not** use `\cvitem` and use an own environment `myitemize`:

```
\newenvironment{myitemize}%
  {\begin{list}{}{%
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{\hintscolumnwidth+\separatorcolumnwidth}
    }}%
  {\end{list}}

\newcommand*{\cventrylong}[7][.25em]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\hintscolumnwidth}@{\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}p{\maincolumnwidth}@{}}%
    \raggedleft\hintstyle{#2} &{%
        {\bfseries#3}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    }%
  \end{tabular}%
  \vspace*{-\baselineskip}
  {\vspace{-.25em}
   \small\begin{myitemize}\item #7\end{myitemize}}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}%
}
```

Now you can get an automatic page break in the new environment `myitemize`.

Please see the following MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic} % head 1, body 1
\moderncvcolor{blue}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\phone[mobile]{+123~(45)~678~9101}
\email{first.last@example.com}

\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{myitemize}%
  {\begin{list}{}{%
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{\hintscolumnwidth+\separatorcolumnwidth}
    }}%
  {\end{list}}

\newcommand*{\cventrylong}[7][.25em]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\hintscolumnwidth}@{\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}p{\maincolumnwidth}@{}}%
    \raggedleft\hintstyle{#2} &{%
        {\bfseries#3}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    }%
  \end{tabular}%
  \vspace*{-\baselineskip}
  {\vspace{-.25em}
   \small\begin{myitemize}\item #7\end{myitemize}}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}%
}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle
\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
\vspace*{-\baselineskip}

\section{Some Title}
\cvline{Primary}{\lipsum[1]}
\cvline{Secondary}{\lipsum[2]}

\section{Work Experience}
\subsection{Professional}

\cventrylong{09/16--08/17--2}%
  {Title--3}%
  {Worksplace--4}%
  {City, Country--5}%
  {--6}
  {\lipsum[3-6]--7}

\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image: resulting page break]

Comment: Ok! I get it. Can't we edit the 7th parameter only (keeping 1-6 as it is) with `\newcommand` to split into multiple pages.

Comment: You nailed it! Wow!

Comment: There is a newline before the 7th parameter. So, edited the answer to include `\vspace*{-\baselineskip}`