# Forcing space in \cventry in moderncv

Tags: itemize, moderncv

**Problem/Question**

Currently all the items in environment `itemize` (1. Lorem Ipsum (...) - 4. Lorem Ipsum (...)) are on page 2.

I would like to keep the first item (1. Lorem Ipsum (...)) on the first page and then let the rest (2. Lorem Ipsum (...) and onwards) go to page 2.

I've tried using `\begin{samepage} \end{samepage}` and adding vertical space with `\vspace{}` and `\vfill{}` in between the first item and the second but nothing seems to work.

**Code**

```
    %% start of file `template.tex'.
%% Copyright 2006-2013 Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com).
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License version 1.3c,
% available at http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/.



\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}                             % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{black}                               % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name
%\nopagenumbers{}                                  % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page

%For bulleted list in cventry
\newcommand\mybitem[1]{%
    \parbox[t]{3mm}{\textbullet}\parbox[t]{10cm}{#1}\\[1.6mm]}

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using
%\usepackage{CJKutf8}                              % if you need to use CJK to typeset your resume in Chinese, Japanese or Korean

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}           % for the 'classic' style, if you want to force the width allocated to your name and avoid line breaks. be careful though, the length is normally calculated to avoid any overlap with your personal info; use this at your own typographical risks...

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{curriculum vitae}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\photo[74pt][0.6pt]{DisplayImage}                       % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to, 0.4pt is the thickness of the frame around it (put it to 0pt for no frame) and 'picture' is the name of the picture file
                            % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted

% to show numerical labels in the bibliography (default is to show no labels); only useful if you make citations in your resume
%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
%\makeatother
%\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{[\arabic{enumiv}]}% CONSIDER REPLACING THE ABOVE BY THIS

% bibliography with mutiple entries
%\usepackage{multibib}
%\newcites{book,misc}{{Books},{Others}}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}                          % to typeset your resume in Chinese using CJK
%-----       resume       ---------------------------------------------------------
\makecvtitle

\section{Personal Data}
\cvdoubleitem{Name}{}{}{}
\cvdoubleitem{Born}{}{}{}
\cvdoubleitem{Address}{}{}{}
\cvdoubleitem{}{}{}{}
\cvdoubleitem{Email}{}{}{}
\cvdoubleitem{Linkedin}{}{}{}
\cvdoubleitem{Facebook}{}{}{}

\section{Education}

\cventry{2014}{}{}{}{}{}
\cventry{2011--2014}{}{}{}{}{}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{2008--2011}{}{}{}{}{}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{2005--2008}{}{}{}{}{}

\section{Job experience}
\cventry{2017--} %1
    {Lorem Ipsum} %2
    {Lorem Ipsum} %3
    {Lorem Ipsum} %4
    {} %5
    {
    \begin{itemize}
    \item 1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. 
        \item Magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent. 
        \item In aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi.
        \item In hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus. 
        \item Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas integer. 
        \item Nulla pharetra diam sit amet. Urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. Amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc. Volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus.
    \end{itemize}
        \item 2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. 
        \item Magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent. 
        \item In aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi.
        \item In hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus. 
        \item Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas integer. 
        \item Nulla pharetra diam sit amet. Urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. Amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc. Volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus.
    \end{itemize}
    \item 3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. 
        \item Magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent. 
        \item In aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi.
        \item In hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus. 
        \item Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas integer. 
        \item Nulla pharetra diam sit amet. Urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. Amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc. Volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus.
    \end{itemize}
    \item 4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. 
        \item Magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent. 
        \item In aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi.
        \item In hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus. 
        \item Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas integer. 
        \item Nulla pharetra diam sit amet. Urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. Amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc. Volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus.
    \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
    } %6  
\end{document}


%% end of file `template.tex'.
```

Comment: Can you add a `% ---- Cut Here ----` in the code to make clear where you want the page break?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in my answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/403557/16550 I defined a new command `\cventrylong` to fullfill your needs:

```
\newenvironment{myitemize}%
  {\begin{list}{}{%
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{\hintscolumnwidth+\separatorcolumnwidth}
    }}%
  {\end{list}}

\newcommand*{\cventrylong}[7][.25em]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\hintscolumnwidth}@{\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}p{\maincolumnwidth}@{}}%
    \raggedleft\hintstyle{#2} &{%
        {\bfseries#3}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    }%
  \end{tabular}%
  \vspace*{-\baselineskip}
  {\vspace{-.25em}
   \small\begin{myitemize}\item #7\end{myitemize}}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}%
}
```

The used environment `myitemize` allows an page break inside. To use it you need to use command `\cventrylong` in your cv.

See the following complete MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{black}

%For bulleted list in cventry
\newcommand\mybitem[1]{%
    \parbox[t]{3mm}{\textbullet}\parbox[t]{10cm}{#1}\\[1.6mm]}

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403541/break-moderncv-cventry-into-multiple-pages-without-using-list-items
\newenvironment{myitemize}%
  {\begin{list}{}{%
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{\hintscolumnwidth+\separatorcolumnwidth}
    }}%
  {\end{list}}

\newcommand*{\cventrylong}[7][.25em]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\hintscolumnwidth}@{\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}p{\maincolumnwidth}@{}}%
    \raggedleft\hintstyle{#2} &{%
        {\bfseries#3}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    }%
  \end{tabular}%
  \vspace*{-\baselineskip}
  {\vspace{-.25em}
   \small\begin{myitemize}\item #7\end{myitemize}}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}%
}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{curriculum vitae}
\photo[74pt][0.6pt]{example-image}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Personal Data}
\cvdoubleitem{Name}{}{}{}
\cvdoubleitem{Born}{}{}{}
\cvdoubleitem{Address}{}{}{}
\cvdoubleitem{}{}{}{}
\cvdoubleitem{Email}{}{}{}
\cvdoubleitem{Linkedin}{}{}{}
\cvdoubleitem{Facebook}{}{}{}

\section{Education}

\cventry{2014}{}{}{}{}{}
\cventry{2011--2014}{}{}{}{}{}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{2008--2011}{}{}{}{}{}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{2005--2008}{}{}{}{}{}

\section{Job experience}
\cventrylong{2017--} %1 <===============================================
    {Lorem Ipsum} %2
    {Lorem Ipsum} %3
    {Lorem Ipsum} %4
    {} %5
    {
    \begin{itemize}
    \item 1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. 
        \item Magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent. 
        \item In aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi.
        \item In hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus. 
        \item Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas integer. 
        \item Nulla pharetra diam sit amet. Urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. Amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc. Volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus.
    \end{itemize}
        \item 2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. 
        \item Magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent. 
        \item In aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi.
        \item In hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus. 
        \item Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas integer. 
        \item Nulla pharetra diam sit amet. Urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. Amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc. Volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus.
    \end{itemize}
    \item 3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. 
        \item Magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent. 
        \item In aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi.
        \item In hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus. 
        \item Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas integer. 
        \item Nulla pharetra diam sit amet. Urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. Amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc. Volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus.
    \end{itemize}
    \item 4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. 
        \item Magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent. 
        \item In aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi.
        \item In hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus. 
        \item Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas integer. 
        \item Nulla pharetra diam sit amet. Urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. Amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc. Volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus.
    \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
    } %6  
\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image: resulting pages 1 and 2]

If you want to get an page break at a special point you can add `\clearpage` between to `\items` like

```
\section{Job experience}
\cventrylong{2017--} %1 <===============================================
    {Lorem Ipsum} %2
    {Lorem Ipsum} %3
    {Lorem Ipsum} %4
    {} %5
    {
    \begin{itemize}
    \item 1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. 
        \item Magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent. 
        \item In aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi.
        \item In hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus. 
        \item Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas integer. 
        \item Nulla pharetra diam sit amet. Urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. Amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc. Volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus.
    \end{itemize}
    \clearpage % <======================================================
        \item 2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
    \begin{itemize}
```

with the result:

[image]

Have you considered to use `enumerate` instead of `itemize` like:

```
\begin{enumerate} % <==============================================
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
\begin{itemize}
    \item Urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. 
    \item Magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent. 
    \item In aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi.
    \item In hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus. 
    \item Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas integer. 
    \item Nulla pharetra diam sit amet. Urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. Amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc. Volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus.
\end{itemize}
\clearpage % <======================================================
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
\begin{itemize}
    \item Urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. 
    \item Magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent. 
    \item In aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi.
    \item In hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus. 
    \item Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas integer. 
    \item Nulla pharetra diam sit amet. Urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. Amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc. Volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus.
\end{itemize}
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
\begin{itemize}
    \item Urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. 
    \item Magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent. 
    \item In aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi.
    \item In hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus. 
    \item Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas integer. 
    \item Nulla pharetra diam sit amet. Urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. Amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc. Volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus.
\end{itemize}
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
\begin{itemize}
    \item Urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. 
    \item Magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent. 
    \item In aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi.
    \item In hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus. 
    \item Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas integer. 
    \item Nulla pharetra diam sit amet. Urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. Amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc. Volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus.
\end{itemize}
\end{enumerate} % <==========================================
```

giving the result:

[image]

Comment: Your answers are always impeccable, too. My compliments. When I see the red arrows and numbers (I think created with the paint pen) I'm sure it's you without reading the user. My sincere greetings and good work.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks for your compliments :-)  I'm using the snipping tool, coming with windows, to be able to mark important thing in my screenshots. There is indeed a pen available I use to do my red markings ...