# How to cleanly forbid page break

Tags: page-breaking, enumitem

In order to allow multi-page `\cvitem` in moderncv, I took that [code here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168537/how-to-insert-multiple-paragraphs-in-a-cventry/168549?noredirect=1#comment1742763_168549). Unfortunately, I can't find how to forbid a new line to occur between the title and the content when the item is close to a page break:

[image]

I tried to add `\nobreakpage` all over the place, without luck. For now, my only solution is to use `\NeedSpace{5\baseline}` before the item, but it looks quite dirty.

If you also have some advices on how to debug that, I'd love to hear as I often get this kind of issues.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{moderntimeline}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} % ?? This breaks moderntimeline?? See the flying 2018?

\tlmaxdates{2012}{2024}
\tlrunningcolor{gray}

\firstname{foo}
\familyname{bar}
\title{foo}
\address{}
\email{}

% This brings multiline items
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168537/how-to-insert-multiple-paragraphs-in-a-cventry/168549
\makeatletter
\def\useCustomEnumItem{}
\ifdefined\useCustomEnumItem
  \usepackage{enumitem}

  \renewcommand{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
    \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
      {\bfseries#3}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\detokenize{#4}}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\detokenize{#5}}{}}{}{, #5}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\detokenize{#6}}{}}{}{, #6}%
      .\strut\ifthenelse{\equal{\detokenize{#7}}{}}{\vspace{1.1mm}}{%
        \nopagebreak%
        \newline%
        \nopagebreak%
        {\small\strut \nopagebreak#7\par}}}}%

  % \renewcommand{\cvitem}[3][.25em]{%
  \renewcommand{\cvitem}[3][.25em]{%
    \begin{mycvlist}%
    \item[{\parbox[t][.85em]{\hintscolumnwidth}{\raggedleft #2}}]#3%
    \end{mycvlist}%
    \nopagebreak%
    \addvspace{#1}%
    \nopagebreak%
  }

  \newlist{mycvlist}{description}{1}
  \setlist[mycvlist]{labelwidth=\hintscolumnwidth,labelsep=\separatorcolumnwidth,align=right,leftmargin=!,font=\normalfont,nosep,
  }
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Hello\vspace{23cm}

Foo

\section{Test}

\tlcventry{2018}{2019}{Some stuff}{Some place}{Foo}{Bla}{
  \begin{itemize}[beginpenalty=10000]
  \item Hey, I am a list
  \item Hey, I am a list
  \item Hey, I am a list
  \item Hey, I am a list
  \item Hey, I am a list
  \item Hey, I am a list
  \end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: set beginparpenalty to 10000 for the list.

Comment: also you are putting vspace and nopagebreak in horizontal mode after a strut which is weird, the behaviour is much clearer if you add them in vmode

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I also tried (with `\begin{itemize}[beginpenalty=10000]`) but same problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and @UlrikeFischer Oh, `\nopagebreak` is not working in horizontal mode? So indeed, if I use `\par\nopagebreak` instead of `\nopagebreak\newline\nopagebreak` AND `[beginpenalty=10000]` it seems to work, thanks! Now, I have a quite large space, but if I also add `\par\nopagebreak\vspace{-\baselineskip}\nopagebreak` before the list it seems to work :-) Is it the cleanest solution?

Comment: it works but is inserted after paragraph breaking, after the line that has that node (so after the firstline of the paragraph, not before the paragraph). the same is true of `vspace`.

Comment: yes putting `\par` before `\vspace` and/or `\nopagebreak` is always better than not doing `\par` But needing to add negative space is always a sign that something is wrong (a `\strut` here) better not add the wrong space than add it and back up over it

Comment: I see, thanks! But I’m not sure to understand your first comment.

Comment: Instead of forbidding it just before the list, maybe it can work out to tell that before the new section is a good place to break? A `\pagebreak[X]`, where `X` is some number. But I don't know how that would work out in practice, though.