# How to keep description label together with first element of multiple nested environments?

Tags: samepage

I have this setup:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
  \item [Heading]~
  \begin{quote}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item First
      \item Second
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{quote}
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

I know of the `samepage` package but that seems not to help since I cannot easily split up the enumerate's first item to put it together in a `samepage`.

Also, I do not like the `needspace` approach since, if I understood it correctly, I would need to know how long my First enumerate item is. But I don't want to set that manually.

Is there a way to tell LaTeX just to keep the Heading and First item **together**?

**Edit**

Here is some illustration.

This should not happen:

```
Heading
---- new page ----
    1. First
    2. Second
```

If there is enough space below the heading, then this would be fine:

```
Heading
    1. First
---- new page ----
    2. Second
```

Otherwise

```
---- new page ----
Heading
    1. First
    2. Second
```

Also, I guess it makes sense that part of the first item might be on the first page and part on the second, if first item goes over several lines.

```
Heading
    1. First First First First First First 
       First First First First First First
---- new page ----
       First First First First First First 
       First First First First First First
    2. Second
```

Comment: Is there a need for using the `quote` environment?

Comment: @Werner Yes. I am quoting someone else's enumeration.

Comment: Do you just have one **Heading** or is this something that is spread throughout your document? Do you have a `twoside` document?

Comment: @Werner This happens at several occasions in my document. It is only onesided.

Comment: In your current example your **Heading** *just* fits within the margin and enumeration (because of `quote`). What should happen if **Heading** is wider than this gap?

Comment: @Werner That it fits the indentation is not on purpose. So the heading could just be longer.

Comment: Could you provide same examples of how this should be handled, perhaps as images or ASCII, so it can be made clear of all your possible cases?

Comment: @Werner Sure. I tried to illustrate it. Does that help?

Comment: quote is a list, see eg http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2645/2388 how to suppress break points before a list. With enumitem you can also set beginpenalty.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks. The custom commands `\mynobreakpar` and `\nolisttopbreak` seem not to work for me. The first has no effect while the latter moves the First item all the way up right behind the Heading or has no effect as well-depending on where I put it. `\@beginparpenalty=10000` seems to work. Is there a way to use it only locally for a certain list?