# Forced jump to next page within enumerate/itemize list

Tags: lists, page-breaking, transition

I want to write inserted list, i.e to write enumerate list whose items will be simple itemize lists (not too large, about 4...8 items).

How to make forced jump to next page in order to not separate title of itemize sublist from itself or not to gap it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question is unclear, you can explain your problem best if you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). But I am pretty sure there is already a similar question here, e.g. [How to prevent a page break before an itemize list?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2644/78783).

Comment: Anything placed in a minipage or \parbox will not split over page breaks.  You might want to add a \vfil in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
  \begin{itemize}
  \item foo
  \item foo
  \item foo
  \end{itemize}
  \clearpage
\item
  \begin{itemize}
  \item bar
  \item bar
  \item bar
  \end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```