# Remove the vertical spacing in Itemize environment?

Tags: page-breaking, itemize

Here is an example of the code for a CV. As it compiles, the first page gave a lot of white space. I would like to split the text so that part of the text is at the next page and part on the first page. As long as the white space is filled. What would be a good way to do this?

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')



% modern themes

\moderncvstyle[norules]{banking}                            % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'

% Reduce the spacing in between address and mobile personal information ====>
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makehead}{%search
  \flushmakeheaddetails\@firstmakeheaddetailselementtrue\\\null}{%replace
  \flushmakeheaddetails\@firstmakeheaddetailselementtrue\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}\null}{%success
  }{%failure
  }
\makeatother


\moderncvcolor{black}                                % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name
%\nopagenumbers{}                                  % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using
%\usepackage{CJKutf8}                              % if you need to use CJK to typeset your resume in Chinese, Japanese or Korean

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}           % for the 'classic' style, if you want to force the width allocated to your name and avoid line breaks. be careful though, the length is normally calculated to avoid any overlap with your personal info; use this at your own typographical risks...

%Additional Packages
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{changepage}

% personal data
\name{\fontsize{22}{22}\selectfont Ted}{\fontsize{22}{22}\selectfont Yang}
\vspace{-1cm}
%\title{Physics}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\address{MR Equivalent Driving License}{New Zealand Citizen}{} % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty

\phone[mobile]{0466-333-520}
                  % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\phone[fixed]{01234 123456}                    % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}                      % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\email{ted.jobs.yang@gmail.com} 
\social[linkedin][https://www.linkedin.com/in/ted-yang-53817049/]{Ted-Yang}                        % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted

%\homepage{www.myname.webs.com}                         % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\extrainfo{additional information}                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}                       % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to, 0.4pt is the thickness of the frame around it (put it to 0pt for no frame) and 'picture' is the name of the picture file
%\quote{Some quote}                                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted

% to show numerical labels in the bibliography (default is to show no labels); only useful if you make citations in your resume
%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
%\makeatother
%\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{[\arabic{enumiv}]}% CONSIDER REPLACING THE ABOVE BY THIS

% Define \cvdoublecolumn, which sets its arguments in two columns without any labels

\newcommand{\cvdoublecolumn}[2]{%
  \cvitem[0.75em]{}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\listdoubleitemcolumnwidth}#1\end{minipage}%
    \hfill%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\listdoubleitemcolumnwidth}#2\end{minipage}%
    }%
}

% usage: \cvreference{name}{address line 1}{address line 2}{address line 3}{address line 4}{e-mail address}{phone number}
% Everything but the name is optional
% If \addresssymbol, \emailsymbol or \phonesymbol are specified, they will be used.
% (Per default, \addresssymbol isn't specified, the other two are specified.)
% If you don't like the symbols, remove them from the following code, including the tilde ~ (space).

\newcommand{\cvreference}[7]{%
    \textbf{#1}\newline% Name
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{\addresssymbol~#2\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{#3\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{#4\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{#5\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{\emailsymbol~\texttt{#6}\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{}}{}{\phonesymbol~#7}}


\linespread{1.15}

% bibliography with mutiple entries
%\usepackage{multibib}
%\newcites{book,misc}{{Books},{Others}}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}                          % to typeset your resume in Chinese using CJK
%-----       resume       ---------------------------------------------------------

\makecvtitle 

\vspace{-8ex}
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{2 pt}}
\vspace{-5ex}
\begin{center}
\fontsize{18}{18} \bfseries Mechatronics \hspace{0.2cm} Engineering \hspace{0.2cm} Professional \\
\large $\blacktriangleright$ Aerospace $\blacktriangleright$ Medical $\blacktriangleright$ High-tech Products  
\end{center}
\vspace{-2.5ex}
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{2 pt}}

Trained and qualified mechatronics engineer with three years of engineering experience across electronics, medical and aviation product manufacturing, servicing, and development. Currently pursuing a Master of Professional Engineering in Aerospace at University of Sydney, I aspire to contribute my knowledge in the aviation defence industry in the area of simulator software and control system design. 
 \vspace{-1ex}\\
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1.2 pt}}
\vspace{-8ex}
\begin{center}
\LARGE
\section{Key Strengths}
\end{center}
\vspace{-2.9ex}
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1.2 pt}}

\begin{itemize}[label=$\bullet$,leftmargin=1cm]
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}

%    \item Electronics circuit diagnostic 
%    \vspace{-0.6ex}
 %   \item Electronics Instrumentation
 %   \vspace{-0.6ex}
 %   \item Product technical support
 %   \vspace{-0.6ex}
 %    \item Product servicing and calibration
 %    \vspace{-0.6ex}
     \item Technical writing and reporting
     \vspace{-0.6ex}
 %   \item Performance Auditing
 %    \vspace{-0.6ex}
 %    \item Production quality control
 %    \vspace{-0.6ex}
    \item Product assembly 
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.62\linewidth}
 %   \item Soldering 
 %   \vspace{-0.6ex}
 %   \item Customer/Contractor liaison
 %   \vspace{-0.6ex}    
    \item Programming in Matlab/Simulink, Python, C++
 %   \vspace{-0.6ex} 
 %   \item ANSYS CFD Simulations
 %   \vspace{-0.6ex}
 %   \item Continuous Improvement/LEAN principles
 %   \vspace{-0.6ex}
    \item Project management experience
 %   \vspace{-0.6ex}
 %   \item Solidworks CAD \& Finite Element Analysis 
 %   \vspace{-0.6ex}
 %   \item Aerospace Design
 \end{minipage}
\end{itemize}
\vspace{-1.5 ex} 
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1.2 pt}}
\vspace{-6.5ex}
\begin{center}
\section{Professional Experience}
\end{center}
\vspace{-2.9ex}
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1.2 pt}}
 \vspace{0ex}
\cventry{Aug 2016 -- Jan 2017}{\bfseries Engineer – (Secondment to Engineering)}{\underline{Martin Aircraft Company Ltd}}{Christchurch}{} 
{\centering Martin Aircraft Company is the world leader in Jetpack development and commercialisation. }
{\setlength\parindent{24pt} \underline{\textit{Key Responsibilities and Accomplishments}} \\
\vspace{-2ex}
\normalsize
\begin{adjustwidth}{12pt}{} 
\begin{enumerate}
\item Worked within the simulation team with external contractor Mathworks to improve on the company’s Jetpack simulation model. This involves extraction of various high-quality test data from flight data sources to produce flight data sets. The data sets are packaged and sent to Mathworks for augmentation of the simulation model. 
\vspace{-1ex}
\item Worked within the flight physics team to analyse flight anomalies such as side slips and investigation of possible causes. This involves writing Matlab functions to automate data extraction and plots, apply research and strong analytical skills, and present information using PowerPoint in a clear concise way. The findings helped validate team member’s CFD analysis as well as providing evidence to suggested hypothesis.    
\vspace{-1ex} 
\item Successfully implemented flight trajectory visualisation tool using Matlab/Simulink requested by the head of flight physics to facilitate extraction of test data. Trajectory visualisation using FlightGear is used for simulation design approach to improving on the Jetpack’s flight dynamic model and provides a real-time feedback of the model given pilot inputs. This tool configures Matlab Simulink to interface with FlightGear.                      
\end{enumerate}
\end{adjustwidth}
}
\linespread{1.2}
\vspace{-2.5ex}
\cventry{Feb 2016 -- Aug 2016}{\bfseries General Technician – Test Operations}{}{}{} 
{
\vspace{-5ex} 
\normalsize
\begin{adjustwidth}{12pt}{}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Provided technical support in flight testing related duties including EMI testing/ RF environmental profiling, designing mechanical fixtures for flight course requirement, writing engineering change requests for implementation on approval and supervision, replacing Jetpack components during testing under supervision.    
\vspace{-1ex} 
\item Acted as centre of excellence as requested by director of flight operations for a temporary indoor flight testing site as well as the company hangar, where I was responsible for writing up on-site safety operation manuals, ensuring site power generator is replenished of fuel, continuous improvement according to budget for flight testing site including designing a Jetpack testing platform, sourcing equipment for flight testing, and liaising with contractors to resolve problems outside of company scope.            
\end{enumerate}
\end{adjustwidth}
}
 \vspace{-0.5ex}
\cventry{Jun 2014 -- Aug 2015}{\bfseries Production Engineer}{\underline{PowerbyProxi Ltd (now Apple NZ)}}{Auckland}{NZ} 
{\centering PowerbyProxi Ltd. contributed research and development and commercialisation of wireless power technology electronic/electrical products, which was acquired by Apple in 2017.}
{\setlength\parindent{24pt} \underline{\textit{Key Responsibilities and Accomplishments}} \\
\vspace{-2.5ex} 
\begin{adjustwidth}{12pt}{}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Promoted from manufacturing service technician to take charge of production of quality inductive power transfer coils involving prototyping the design, build methodology, coil quality control, and production tracking using Excel.
\vspace{-1ex}
\item Reduced production time of an industrial wireless power transfer product by two third of its original production time by conducting a time study to identify production bottleneck and building three custom test jigs on my own. The result is successfully delivering targets on time.
\vspace{-1ex}
\item Provided guidance and training of 6 to 7 product assemblers in lieu of operations manager as well as engaged in product assembly. Conducted quality control/spot checks on the finishing product and trained new workers on correct production procedures on PowerbyProxi’s product line up.               
\vspace{-1ex}
\item Assisted operations manager on production related activities including production site continuous improvement and OSH management, Solidworks mechanical parts manufacturing drawing, replenishing stock, and technical documentation.          
\end{enumerate}
\end{adjustwidth}
}
\vspace{-2.5ex}
\cventry{Feb 2014 -- Jun 2014}{\bfseries Manufacturing Service Technician - Casual}{}{}{NZ}
\normalsize 
{\vspace{-6.5ex} 
\begin{adjustwidth}{12pt}{}
\item Successfully  designed the manufacturing process for several experimental coils for experimental purposes and therefore contributed to the overall company objective in its experimental pursuit milestones.
\end{adjustwidth}
}
\vspace{-2.5ex} 
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1.2 pt}}
\vspace{-8ex}
\begin{center}
\LARGE
\section{Qualification \& Awards}
\end{center}
\vspace{-2.9ex}
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1.2 pt}}
\raggedright
\cventry{Mar 2018--present}{Master of Professional Engineering}{University of Sydney}{Sydney, Australia}{\textit{Aerospace}}
{}
\vspace{-0.5ex}
\begin{adjustwidth}{24pt}{}
Receiver of a Commonwealth Supported Place for reduced fee study. Weighted Average Mark at distinction level.
\end{adjustwidth}

\cventry{Mar 2010-- Nov 2013}{Bachelor of Engineering (Hons)}{University of Auckland}{Auckland, New Zealand}{\textit{Mechatronics}}
{\setlength\parindent{24pt} \underline{\textit{Accomplishments}}} 
\vspace{-3.5ex} 
\cventry{2013}{\setlength\parindent{24pt} \textbf{Fire Extinguishing Robot Design Top of Class Award}}{}{}{}
{}
\begin{adjustwidth}{24pt}{}
Led a four-person-project with only two members, who happened to drop out of their degrees due to personal circumstances, kept track of project progress, allocated tasks in mechanical chassis design, sensors integration, data acquisition software programming, and electronic circuit design. Required to work under pressure to achieve all requirement of the project by working at a fast pace and putting in extra hours. As a result, the robot achieved second fastest fire extinguishing time.   
\end{adjustwidth}
\vspace{-3.5ex} 
\cventry{2012}{\setlength\parindent{24pt} \textbf{ZOME Design + Build Competition Runner Up Award}}{}{}{}
{}
\begin{adjustwidth}{24pt}{}
Led a team of four to compete in the annual ZOME Design + Build Competition sponsored by Fletcher Construction. Solely responsible for coordinating the team in the brainstorming, SWOT analysis and project management to track performance of the team to achieve desired outcome. Our team achieved second place in the man-made category (categories: man-made vs. nature) out of 24 teams.   
\end{adjustwidth}
\vspace{-2ex} 
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1.2 pt}}
\vspace{-9ex}
\begin{center}
\LARGE
\vspace{-1ex}
\section{Other Work Experience and Skills}
\end{center}
\vspace{-2.9ex}
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1.2 pt}}
\cventry{Feb 2019 -- Present}{\bfseries Dnata Customer Delivery – Casual Part Time}{\underline{Qantas Catering (now Dnata) Ltd}}{Sydney}{AU} 
{\centering Dnata is one of the leading global brands in airline operations services.}
{}
\cventry{Oct 2017 -- Feb 2018}{\bfseries Airline Catering Driver – Casual}{\underline{Gate Gourmet Ltd}}{Auckland}{NZ} 
{\centering Gate Gourmet is a leading global provider of a full range of catering services for today’s airline industry.}
\cventry{Aug 2017 -- Sep 2017}{\bfseries Production Test and Assembler – 1 Month Fixed Term}{\underline{Cubic Defence Ltd}}{Auckland}{NZ} 
{\centering Cubic Defence New Zealand Limited develops and markets simulation training systems for the military, law enforcement, and police training markets.}

\cventry{Mar 2017 -- Jul 2017}{\bfseries Electromechanical Test and Assembly Technician – Contract                                       }{\underline{Buckley Systems Ltd - Medical Device Contract}}{Auckland}{NZ} 
{\centering Buckley Systems Limited manufactures specialised electromagnets in volumes of thousands and delivers innovative custom electromagnetic solutions to fortune 500 companies around the world.}
{
\begin{adjustwidth}{12pt}{} 
Contracted to assemble and test the latest custom electromagnetic solution for medical use. Primary purpose is to make a particular Cancer treatment a practical proposition. Learnt about regulatory record-keeping processes to certify medical products. 
\end{adjustwidth}
}
 \vspace{-0.5ex}
\iffalse
\cventry{Apr 2014 -- Jun 2014}{\bfseries Calibration Technician}{\underline{TechRentals Ltd}}{Auckland}{NZ}
{\centering TechRentals provide technical instrumentation solutions for your short and long term test and measurement requirements.} 
{ \begin{adjustwidth}{12pt}{} 
\begin{enumerate}
\item Developed knowledge of calibration testing standards and procedures as well as operating calibration instrument
\vspace{-0.5ex}
\item Gained professional customer facing experience 
\end{enumerate}
\end{adjustwidth}
}
\fi
\vspace{-2ex} 
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1.2 pt}}
\vspace{-9ex}
\begin{center}
\LARGE
\section{Interests and Extra-curricular Activity}
\end{center}
\normalsize
\vspace{-3ex}
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1.2 pt}}
\cventry{Aug 2018 -- Oct 2018}{
\vspace{-0.5ex}
\textbf{Volunteer Peer Mentoring}}{University of Sydney Peer Mentoring Program}{Sydney}{}{}
\vspace{-0.5ex} 
Organised fortnightly events to help fellow postgraduate students settle into Sydney campus life.   
\cventry{Dec 2011 -- Jan 2012}{\textbf{Volunteer Conservation Projects}}{International Student Volunteer (ISV)}{Costa Rica}{}{}
\vspace{-0.5ex} 
Hiked in rainforests and took samples of tree frogs in terms of their size and gender and travelled across the sea to pinpoint dolphin locations and recorded samples of dolphin types, and behaviours to update the local conservation data. \\
\vspace{-0.1cm}
\textbf{Interests} \\
\vspace{-3ex}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{itemize}[label=$\bullet$,leftmargin=24pt]
        \item Cooking (All Kinds of Cuisines)
        \vspace{-2ex}
        \item Outdoor Activities (Camping, Travelling)
        \vspace{-2ex}
        \item Music – Jazz Drumming
        \vspace{-2ex}
        \item Sports – Tennis, Basketball, Gym
       \end{itemize}
    \end{multicols}
%\vspace{-3.5ex}
%\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1.2 pt}}
%\vspace{-8ex}
\iffalse
\begin{center}
\LARGE
\section{References}
\end{center}
\vspace{-2.9ex}
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1.2 pt}}
\cvdoublecolumn{\cvreference{Prospero 'Paco' Uybarreta }
    {Chief Test Pilot - Department of Flight Operations}
    {Martin Aircraft Company}
    {39 Ballarat Way, Wigram}
    {Christchurch 8042, New Zealand}
    {prospero.uybarreta@martinaircraft.co.nz}
    {+64-21-462-315}
    }
    {\cvreference{Dr. Doug Auld}
    {Senior Lecturer - School of Aerospace, Mechanical and Mechatronic Engineering}
    {University of Sydney}
    {City Road, Sydney}
    {New South Wales 2006, Australia}
    {doug.auld@sydney.edu.au}
    {+61-2-9351-2336}
    }
\fi
\begin{center}
\iffalse
\LARGE
\section{References}
\vspace{-2.3ex}
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1.2 pt}}
\fi
% \large
 \vspace{0cm}
 \large
\textbf{References available on request}.
\end{center}

% Publications from a BibTeX file without multibib
%  for numerical labels: \renewcommand{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}% CONSIDER MERGING WITH PREAMBLE PART
%  to redefine the heading string ("Publications"): \renewcommand{\refname}{Articles}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{publications}                        % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file

% Publications from a BibTeX file using the multibib package
%\section{Publications}
%\nocitebook{book1,book2}
%\bibliographystylebook{plain}
%\bibliographybook{publications}                   % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file
%\nocitemisc{misc1,misc2,misc3}
%\bibliographystylemisc{plain}
%\bibliographymisc{publications}                   % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file

%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

The result of the compile gives this as the first page: 
[image]

ideally I wanted to split the list in order to fill the white space. I have tried /vspace however it does not work as too much vspace will cover the text above.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX,SE! Please make your document example much shorter. If you have problem with lists, reduce it to showing one, which you like to improve. Now from forest trees can not be seen :-(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great question and Welcome to TeX SE! Here is a solution to your problem. My answer was inspired by another Stack Exchange chat that you can consult: [How to prevent a page break before an itemize list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2644/how-to-prevent-a-page-break-before-an-itemize-list/46795#46795)

The MWE

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

% modern themes

\moderncvstyle[norules]{banking}                            % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'

% Reduce the spacing in between address and mobile personal information ====>
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makehead}{%search
  \flushmakeheaddetails\@firstmakeheaddetailselementtrue\\\null}{%replace
  \flushmakeheaddetails\@firstmakeheaddetailselementtrue\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}\null}{%success
  }{%failure
  }
\makeatother

\moderncvcolor{black}                                % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name
%\nopagenumbers{}                                  % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using
%\usepackage{CJKutf8}                              % if you need to use CJK to typeset your resume in Chinese, Japanese or Korean

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}           % for the 'classic' style, if you want to force the width allocated to your name and avoid line breaks. be careful though, the length is normally calculated to avoid any overlap with your personal info; use this at your own typographical risks...

%Additional Packages
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{changepage}

% personal data
\name{\fontsize{22}{22}\selectfont Ted}{\fontsize{22}{22}\selectfont Yang}
\vspace{-1cm}
%\title{Physics}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\address{MR Equivalent Driving License}{New Zealand Citizen}{} % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty

\phone[mobile]{0466-333-520}
% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\phone[fixed]{01234 123456}                    % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}                      % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\email{ted.jobs.yang@gmail.com} 
\social[linkedin][https://www.linkedin.com/in/ted-yang-53817049/]{Ted-Yang}                        % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted

%\homepage{www.myname.webs.com}                         % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\extrainfo{additional information}                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}                       % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to, 0.4pt is the thickness of the frame around it (put it to 0pt for no frame) and 'picture' is the name of the picture file
%\quote{Some quote}                                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted

% to show numerical labels in the bibliography (default is to show no labels); only useful if you make citations in your resume
%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
%\makeatother
%\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{[\arabic{enumiv}]}% CONSIDER REPLACING THE ABOVE BY THIS

% Define \cvdoublecolumn, which sets its arguments in two columns without any labels

\newcommand{\cvdoublecolumn}[2]{%
    \cvitem[0.75em]{}{%
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\listdoubleitemcolumnwidth}#1\end{minipage}%
        \hfill%
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\listdoubleitemcolumnwidth}#2\end{minipage}%
    }%
}

% usage: \cvreference{name}{address line 1}{address line 2}{address line 3}{address line 4}{e-mail address}{phone number}
% Everything but the name is optional
% If \addresssymbol, \emailsymbol or \phonesymbol are specified, they will be used.
% (Per default, \addresssymbol isn't specified, the other two are specified.)
% If you don't like the symbols, remove them from the following code, including the tilde ~ (space).

\newcommand{\cvreference}[7]{%
    \textbf{#1}\newline% Name
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{\addresssymbol~#2\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{#3\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{#4\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{#5\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{\emailsymbol~\texttt{#6}\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{}}{}{\phonesymbol~#7}}


\linespread{1.15}

%Created this command that prevents the list from breaking at the bottom of the page. Insert it to the applicable lists where you want this to happen.
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nolisttopbreak}{\vspace{\topsep}\nobreak\@afterheading}
\makeatother

% bibliography with mutiple entries
%\usepackage{multibib}
%\newcites{book,misc}{{Books},{Others}}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
    %\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}                          % to typeset your resume in Chinese using CJK
    %-----       resume       ---------------------------------------------------------

    \makecvtitle 

    \vspace{-8ex}
    \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{2 pt}}
    \vspace{-5ex}
    \begin{center}
        \fontsize{18}{18} \bfseries Mechatronics \hspace{0.2cm} Engineering \hspace{0.2cm} Professional \\
        \large $\blacktriangleright$ Aerospace $\blacktriangleright$ Medical $\blacktriangleright$ High-tech Products  
    \end{center}
    \vspace{-2.5ex}
    \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{2 pt}}

    Trained and qualified mechatronics engineer with three years of engineering experience across electronics, medical and aviation product manufacturing, servicing, and development. Currently pursuing a Master of Professional Engineering in Aerospace at University of Sydney, I aspire to contribute my knowledge in the aviation defence industry in the area of simulator software and control system design. 
    \vspace{-1ex}\\
    \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1.2 pt}}
    \vspace{-8ex}
    \begin{center}
        \LARGE
        \section{Key Strengths}
    \end{center}
    \vspace{-2.9ex}
    \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1.2 pt}}

    \begin{itemize}[label=$\bullet$,leftmargin=1cm]
        \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}

            %    \item Electronics circuit diagnostic 
            %    \vspace{-0.6ex}
            %   \item Electronics Instrumentation
            %   \vspace{-0.6ex}
            %   \item Product technical support
            %   \vspace{-0.6ex}
            %    \item Product servicing and calibration
            %    \vspace{-0.6ex}
            \item Technical writing and reporting
            \vspace{-0.6ex}
            %   \item Performance Auditing
            %    \vspace{-0.6ex}
            %    \item Production quality control
            %    \vspace{-0.6ex}
            \item Product assembly 
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}{0.62\linewidth}
            %   \item Soldering 
            %   \vspace{-0.6ex}
            %   \item Customer/Contractor liaison
            %   \vspace{-0.6ex}    
            \item Programming in Matlab/Simulink, Python, C++
            %   \vspace{-0.6ex} 
            %   \item ANSYS CFD Simulations
            %   \vspace{-0.6ex}
            %   \item Continuous Improvement/LEAN principles
            %   \vspace{-0.6ex}
            \item Project management experience
            %   \vspace{-0.6ex}
            %   \item Solidworks CAD \& Finite Element Analysis 
            %   \vspace{-0.6ex}
            %   \item Aerospace Design
        \end{minipage}
    \end{itemize}
    \vspace{-1.5 ex} 
    \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1.2 pt}}
    \vspace{-6.5ex}
    \begin{center}
        \section{Professional Experience}
    \end{center}
    \vspace{-2.9ex}
    \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1.2 pt}}
    \vspace{0ex}
    \cventry{Aug 2016 -- Jan 2017}{\bfseries Engineer – (Secondment to Engineering)}{\underline{Martin Aircraft Company Ltd}}{Christchurch}{} 
    {\centering Martin Aircraft Company is the world leader in Jetpack development and commercialisation. }
    {\setlength\parindent{24pt} \underline{\textit{Key Responsibilities and Accomplishments}} \\
        \vspace{-2ex}
        \normalsize
        \begin{adjustwidth}{12pt}{} 
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item Worked within the simulation team with external contractor Mathworks to improve on the company’s Jetpack simulation model. This involves extraction of various high-quality test data from flight data sources to produce flight data sets. The data sets are packaged and sent to Mathworks for augmentation of the simulation model. 
                \vspace{-1ex}
                \item Worked within the flight physics team to analyse flight anomalies such as side slips and investigation of possible causes. This involves writing Matlab functions to automate data extraction and plots, apply research and strong analytical skills, and present information using PowerPoint in a clear concise way. The findings helped validate team member’s CFD analysis as well as providing evidence to suggested hypothesis.    
                \vspace{-1ex} 
                \item Successfully implemented flight trajectory visualisation tool using Matlab/Simulink requested by the head of flight physics to facilitate extraction of test data. Trajectory visualisation using FlightGear is used for simulation design approach to improving on the Jetpack’s flight dynamic model and provides a real-time feedback of the model given pilot inputs. This tool configures Matlab Simulink to interface with FlightGear.                      
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{adjustwidth}
    }
    \linespread{1.2}
    \vspace{-2.5ex}
    \cventry{Feb 2016 -- Aug 2016}{\bfseries General Technician – Test Operations}{}{}{} 
    \nolisttopbreak %NEW Command for preventings list break
    ~\
    {
        \vspace{-5ex} 
        \normalsize
        \begin{adjustwidth}{12pt}{}
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item Provided technical support in flight testing related duties including EMI testing/ RF environmental profiling, designing mechanical fixtures for flight course requirement, writing engineering change requests for implementation on approval and supervision, replacing Jetpack components during testing under supervision.    
                \vspace{-1ex} 
                \item Acted as centre of excellence as requested by director of flight operations for a temporary indoor flight testing site as well as the company hangar, where I was responsible for writing up on-site safety operation manuals, ensuring site power generator is replenished of fuel, continuous improvement according to budget for flight testing site including designing a Jetpack testing platform, sourcing equipment for flight testing, and liaising with contractors to resolve problems outside of company scope.            
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{adjustwidth}
    }
    \vspace{-0.5ex}
    \cventry{Jun 2014 -- Aug 2015}{\bfseries Production Engineer}{\underline{PowerbyProxi Ltd (now Apple NZ)}}{Auckland}{NZ} 
    {\centering PowerbyProxi Ltd. contributed research and development and commercialisation of wireless power technology electronic/electrical products, which was acquired by Apple in 2017.}
    {\setlength\parindent{24pt} \underline{\textit{Key Responsibilities and Accomplishments}} \\
        \vspace{-2.5ex} 
        \begin{adjustwidth}{12pt}{}
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item Promoted from manufacturing service technician to take charge of production of quality inductive power transfer coils involving prototyping the design, build methodology, coil quality control, and production tracking using Excel.
                \vspace{-1ex}
                \item Reduced production time of an industrial wireless power transfer product by two third of its original production time by conducting a time study to identify production bottleneck and building three custom test jigs on my own. The result is successfully delivering targets on time.
                \vspace{-1ex}
                \item Provided guidance and training of 6 to 7 product assemblers in lieu of operations manager as well as engaged in product assembly. Conducted quality control/spot checks on the finishing product and trained new workers on correct production procedures on PowerbyProxi’s product line up.               
                \vspace{-1ex}
                \item Assisted operations manager on production related activities including production site continuous improvement and OSH management, Solidworks mechanical parts manufacturing drawing, replenishing stock, and technical documentation.          
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{adjustwidth}
    }
    \vspace{-2.5ex}
    \cventry{Feb 2014 -- Jun 2014}{\bfseries Manufacturing Service Technician - Casual}{}{}{NZ}
    \normalsize 
    {\vspace{-6.5ex} 
        \begin{adjustwidth}{12pt}{}
            \item Successfully  designed the manufacturing process for several experimental coils for experimental purposes and therefore contributed to the overall company objective in its experimental pursuit milestones.
        \end{adjustwidth}
    }
    \vspace{-2.5ex} 
    \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1.2 pt}}
    \vspace{-8ex}
    \begin{center}
        \LARGE
        \section{Qualification \& Awards}
    \end{center}
    \vspace{-2.9ex}
    \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1.2 pt}}
    \raggedright
    \cventry{Mar 2018--present}{Master of Professional Engineering}{University of Sydney}{Sydney, Australia}{\textit{Aerospace}}
    {}
    \vspace{-0.5ex}
    \begin{adjustwidth}{24pt}{}
        Receiver of a Commonwealth Supported Place for reduced fee study. Weighted Average Mark at distinction level.
    \end{adjustwidth}

    \cventry{Mar 2010-- Nov 2013}{Bachelor of Engineering (Hons)}{University of Auckland}{Auckland, New Zealand}{\textit{Mechatronics}}
    {\setlength\parindent{24pt} \underline{\textit{Accomplishments}}} 
    \vspace{-3.5ex} 
    \cventry{2013}{\setlength\parindent{24pt} \textbf{Fire Extinguishing Robot Design Top of Class Award}}{}{}{}
    {}
    \begin{adjustwidth}{24pt}{}
        Led a four-person-project with only two members, who happened to drop out of their degrees due to personal circumstances, kept track of project progress, allocated tasks in mechanical chassis design, sensors integration, data acquisition software programming, and electronic circuit design. Required to work under pressure to achieve all requirement of the project by working at a fast pace and putting in extra hours. As a result, the robot achieved second fastest fire extinguishing time.   
    \end{adjustwidth}
    \vspace{-3.5ex} 
    \cventry{2012}{\setlength\parindent{24pt} \textbf{ZOME Design + Build Competition Runner Up Award}}{}{}{}
    {}
    \begin{adjustwidth}{24pt}{}
        Led a team of four to compete in the annual ZOME Design + Build Competition sponsored by Fletcher Construction. Solely responsible for coordinating the team in the brainstorming, SWOT analysis and project management to track performance of the team to achieve desired outcome. Our team achieved second place in the man-made category (categories: man-made vs. nature) out of 24 teams.   
    \end{adjustwidth}
    \vspace{-2ex} 
    \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1.2 pt}}
    \vspace{-9ex}
    \begin{center}
        \LARGE
        \vspace{-1ex}
        \section{Other Work Experience and Skills}
    \end{center}
    \vspace{-2.9ex}
    \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1.2 pt}}
    \cventry{Feb 2019 -- Present}{\bfseries Dnata Customer Delivery – Casual Part Time}{\underline{Qantas Catering (now Dnata) Ltd}}{Sydney}{AU} 
    {\centering Dnata is one of the leading global brands in airline operations services.}
    {}
    \cventry{Oct 2017 -- Feb 2018}{\bfseries Airline Catering Driver – Casual}{\underline{Gate Gourmet Ltd}}{Auckland}{NZ} 
    {\centering Gate Gourmet is a leading global provider of a full range of catering services for today’s airline industry.}
    \cventry{Aug 2017 -- Sep 2017}{\bfseries Production Test and Assembler – 1 Month Fixed Term}{\underline{Cubic Defence Ltd}}{Auckland}{NZ} 
    {\centering Cubic Defence New Zealand Limited develops and markets simulation training systems for the military, law enforcement, and police training markets.}

    \cventry{Mar 2017 -- Jul 2017}{\bfseries Electromechanical Test and Assembly Technician – Contract                                       }{\underline{Buckley Systems Ltd - Medical Device Contract}}{Auckland}{NZ} 
    {\centering Buckley Systems Limited manufactures specialised electromagnets in volumes of thousands and delivers innovative custom electromagnetic solutions to fortune 500 companies around the world.}
    {
        \begin{adjustwidth}{12pt}{} 
            Contracted to assemble and test the latest custom electromagnetic solution for medical use. Primary purpose is to make a particular Cancer treatment a practical proposition. Learnt about regulatory record-keeping processes to certify medical products. 
        \end{adjustwidth}
    }
    \vspace{-0.5ex}
    \iffalse
    \cventry{Apr 2014 -- Jun 2014}{\bfseries Calibration Technician}{\underline{TechRentals Ltd}}{Auckland}{NZ}
    {\centering TechRentals provide technical instrumentation solutions for your short and long term test and measurement requirements.} 
    { \begin{adjustwidth}{12pt}{} 
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item Developed knowledge of calibration testing standards and procedures as well as operating calibration instrument
                \vspace{-0.5ex}
                \item Gained professional customer facing experience 
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{adjustwidth}
    }
    \fi
    \vspace{-2ex} 
    \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1.2 pt}}
    \vspace{-9ex}
    \begin{center}
        \LARGE
        \section{Interests and Extra-curricular Activity}
    \end{center}
    \normalsize
    \vspace{-3ex}
    \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1.2 pt}}
    \cventry{Aug 2018 -- Oct 2018}{
        \vspace{-0.5ex}
        \textbf{Volunteer Peer Mentoring}}{University of Sydney Peer Mentoring Program}{Sydney}{}{}
    \vspace{-0.5ex} 
    Organised fortnightly events to help fellow postgraduate students settle into Sydney campus life.   
    \cventry{Dec 2011 -- Jan 2012}{\textbf{Volunteer Conservation Projects}}{International Student Volunteer (ISV)}{Costa Rica}{}{}
    \vspace{-0.5ex} 
    Hiked in rainforests and took samples of tree frogs in terms of their size and gender and travelled across the sea to pinpoint dolphin locations and recorded samples of dolphin types, and behaviours to update the local conservation data. \\
    \vspace{-0.1cm}
    \textbf{Interests} \\
    \vspace{-3ex}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{itemize}[label=$\bullet$,leftmargin=24pt]
            \item Cooking (All Kinds of Cuisines)
            \vspace{-2ex}
            \item Outdoor Activities (Camping, Travelling)
            \vspace{-2ex}
            \item Music – Jazz Drumming
            \vspace{-2ex}
            \item Sports – Tennis, Basketball, Gym
        \end{itemize}
    \end{multicols}
    %\vspace{-3.5ex}
    %\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1.2 pt}}
    %\vspace{-8ex}
    \iffalse
    \begin{center}
        \LARGE
        \section{References}
    \end{center}
    \vspace{-2.9ex}
    \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1.2 pt}}
    \cvdoublecolumn{\cvreference{Prospero 'Paco' Uybarreta }
        {Chief Test Pilot - Department of Flight Operations}
        {Martin Aircraft Company}
        {39 Ballarat Way, Wigram}
        {Christchurch 8042, New Zealand}
        {prospero.uybarreta@martinaircraft.co.nz}
        {+64-21-462-315}
    }
    {\cvreference{Dr. Doug Auld}
        {Senior Lecturer - School of Aerospace, Mechanical and Mechatronic Engineering}
        {University of Sydney}
        {City Road, Sydney}
        {New South Wales 2006, Australia}
        {doug.auld@sydney.edu.au}
        {+61-2-9351-2336}
    }
    \fi
    \begin{center}
        \iffalse
        \LARGE
        \section{References}
        \vspace{-2.3ex}
        \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1.2 pt}}
        \fi
        % \large
        \vspace{0cm}
        \large
        \textbf{References available on request}.
    \end{center}

    % Publications from a BibTeX file without multibib
    %  for numerical labels: \renewcommand{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}% CONSIDER MERGING WITH PREAMBLE PART
    %  to redefine the heading string ("Publications"): \renewcommand{\refname}{Articles}
    \nocite{*}
    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    \bibliography{publications}                        % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file

    % Publications from a BibTeX file using the multibib package
    %\section{Publications}
    %\nocitebook{book1,book2}
    %\bibliographystylebook{plain}
    %\bibliographybook{publications}                   % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file
    %\nocitemisc{misc1,misc2,misc3}
    %\bibliographystylemisc{plain}
    %\bibliographymisc{publications}                   % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file

    %-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would consider `enumitem` package for the lists and than use `\begin{enumerate}[nosep]\item ... \item ...\end{enumerate}`.

Comment: Thanks Jen! This works great and also thanks Zarko for the tip.